# can't get MVC3 DDL SelectedValue to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ddl, selectedvalue

This is my VM

```
    public class CountriesViewModel
    {
        public string CurrentCountry { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    }
```

With my Controller

```
    public class FiltersController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult _ShipToCountry(IEnumerable<Country> countries,
                                           string currentCountry = "AE")
        {
            var viewModel = new CountriesViewModel
            {
                Countries = countries.OrderBy(x => x.Name),
                CurrentCountry = currentCountry
            };

            return PartialView(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

And finally the View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Countries,
                      new SelectList(Model.Countries.ToList(),
                                     "Code", "Name", Model.CurrentCountry))
```

Where Model.CurrentCountry is the Code.

The DDL is rendered correctly

```
...
<option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
<option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
....
```

But no Country gets selected, what am I missing?

Comment: @kooshka...looks right. Are you sure "AE" is in the "Code" list for countries

Comment: "AE" is just the default it is on the list for sure. But any other country code that is passed, and it is passed I can see it when debugging, still doesn't select the DDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `CurrentCountry` prop to expression if not also you cannot get the selected country on form submit.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CurrentCountry,
                      new SelectList(Model.Countries.ToList(), "Code", "Name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

Instead of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Countries,
                      new SelectList(Model.Countries.ToList(), 
                                     "Code", "Name", Model.CurrentCountry))
```

Used

```
@Html.DropDownList(Model.CurrentCountry,
                   new SelectList(Model.Countries.ToList(),
                                  "Code", "Name", Model.CurrentCountry))
```